# My project runs but has meaningless errors

Tags: android, compiler-errors

My project runs but has meaningless errors.
Android Studio error all my code but my project runs and creates the apk file for me.

All the files in my project have a meaningless error. All codes are correct, but Android Studio counts it as an error.

I hope this image can to deliver you my Purpose:

    http://s5.picofile.com/file/8363042642/Shot_0001.png

The project has a lot of errors, but the build is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Sync Project with Gradle Files** (icon in the top right corner)

If that doesn't help, try invalidating the cache

> **File** -> **Invalidate Caches / Restart...** -> **Invalidate and Restart**

Comment: Thank a lot. The answer was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

'i think you are using some features of android x to remove this error expend your imports from each class and remove the extra libraries and import the new by pressing Alt+Enter on each class or by clicking mouse right click'

[image]

'hope you get the solutions'